# how to change called class in javascript when button is click?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a div which is

```
<div class="add1"></div>
```

I want the add1 become add+thenumber of length example:

```
var n= $('.add1').length + 1;  
$('.add1').click(function(){
```

so what I did is

```
$('.add+n').click(function(){
```

but it doesnt work, please help me :(

Comment: I can't understand the question.   The `.length` of `.add1` will be however many elements there are with that class.  But then you want to register the handler on a _different_ set of objects that have .`addN` as their class?  This sounds like an XY Problem...

Comment: If one of the answers helped answer your question, please consider accepting that one as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number in a data attribute and increment on every click.
Change the class attribute from the data attribute value.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="myDiv" data-num='1' class="add1">click me</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click', function(){

var num = Number(this.getAttribute('data-num'));
num++;
this.setAttribute('data-num', num)

this.setAttribute('class', 'add' + num);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.add'+n).click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

the n needs to be outside of the quotes else it will interpret it as a string. Like so:

```
$('.add' + n).click(function(){
```

At first i read your question wrong and i thought you wanted to change the div's class accordingly. Which you could do like this:

```
var n = 1;
var n= $('.add'+1).length + 1;  

$('.add' + n).click(function(){
   $(this).attr('class', 'add' + n);  //for if you also want to change the class of the div
});
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here it is!! try this .. I code following  exactly you need.

`<input type="text" style="display:none;" name="qty" value="0" />`

`<p id="inc" class="">It's class will be Increased[concate with number]</p>`

```
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="increase"/>
```

Now following is Main script that will help you ..

```
    var incrementVar = 0;
    $(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1;
        $(":text[name='qty']").val(value);
        $('#inc').removeClass('a' + (value-1));
        $('#inc').addClass('a' + value); // I believe class names cannot start with a number
        incrementVar = incrementVar + value;
    });
});
```

i posted this code also on [www.codedownload.in](http://www.codedownload.in)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add and [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove classes

```
$('.add1').click(function(){
    var n= $('.add1').length + 1; //reads n
    $(".add1").addClass("add"+n); //adds new class
    $(".add"+n).removeClass("add1"); //removes existing class
});
```

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/danimvijay/ssfucy6q/

If you want to select the class with combination of a variable, use `$('.add'+n)` instead of `$('.add+n')`.

```
$('.add'+n).click(function(){
//place code here
});
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/danimvijay/a0j4Latq/